# iPhone app Facebook login with different account than FB app, when Single Sign on is enabled

Tags: iphone, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, single-sign-on

I'd like to use Facebook single sign on (SSO) in my iPhone app, but I would also like to get the option to users to login with a different account from the one they are logged in the official Facebook app. Ideally, the user will be first sent to the Facebook app, but when she refuses to accept the sign on, the control will be sent back to my app. At this point, it would be perfect to show the old in app login view, so that she can use a different userid/password combination. Is that last step possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the proper library (http://three20.info/) for work with Facebook. There are all tools what you will need! 
In your case it will be simple code like:

```
Facebook *_facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:kAppId];
NSArray* _permissions =  [[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"read_stream", @"offline_access",nil] retain];

[_facebook authorize:_permissions delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 0):

When the call the iOS SDK authorize method a dialog will be popped up to ask for permissions if a logged-in user of the Facebook app was found. In that dialog there should be a "Not You?" link that would give the user the option to log in as a different user.

Comment: I tried that. If you hit on "Not You?", at least now and in my case, it doesn't work: it sends me back to Facebook app and the same dialog window. Maybe it's a Facebook issue, or maybe I need to handle that case and I don't. Is it working for you?

Comment: Yes it was working when I sent you the suggestion. I also tried it out with the Foursquare app (newly downloaded, launched app, tapped Facebook registration, clicked Not You?)

Comment: Maybe I need to handle that in some way. In my app, it just returns back to Facebook authorization page with the "Not You?" link. Any idea on how to handle that?

Comment: Can you verify that you have set up SSO correctly, specifically make sure you have set up the URL that will be called back after the Facebook app is called, see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/ for guidance. If you do not set this up you may cycle back to the same window.